# Syntax Error what could it be?

Tags: python, syntax

I have been trying to run this program for a little while now but I can not seem to find out what is causing the error when trying to run it.

Here's the line of code where I'm getting the error:

```
from math import *
from myro import *
init("simulator")

def rps(score):
    """ Asks the user to input a choice, and randomly assigns a choice to the computer."""
    speak("Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
    computerPick = randint(1,3)
    userPick = raw_input("Please enter (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors.")
    if userPick = R <#This line is where the error shows up at>
        print "You picked rock."
    elif userPick = P
        print "You picked paper."
    else
        print "You picked Scissors."
    score = outcome(score, userPick, computerPick)
    return score
```

Comment: *What* is the error? And where exactly? Could you please post the full trace-back error message

Comment: What line and what's the error?

Comment: `import *` is usually a bad idea.  You are asking for name collisions and making your code harder to follow and debug.

Comment: Also, if this is homework, could you please tag it as such?  And check out the PEP8 style guide as well.  Python's preferred coding conventions are different than many other common languages.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the assignment operator instead of equality.  Also, you are missing the colon for your if statements and not quoting your strings.

```
if userPick == 'R':
    ...
elif userPick == 'P':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

I'd note that you shouldn't use `else` for the `'S'` case here though.  `'S'` should be another valid condition, and else should be an error state catchall.

An alternate way to do this would be:

```
input_output_map = {'R' : 'rock', 'P' : 'paper', 'S' : 'scissors'}
try:
    print 'You picked %s.' % input_output_map[user_pick]
except KeyError:
    print 'Invalid selection %s.' % user_pick
```

Or:

```
valid_choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
for choice in valid_choices:
    if user_choice.lower() in (choice, choice[0]):
        print 'You picked %s.' % choice
        break
else:
    print 'Invalid choice %s.' % user_choice
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if userPick = R:
```

should be

```
if userPick == "R":
```